# What does platform.system() and platform.architecture() return on Apple M1 Silicon?

Tags: python-3.x, architecture, system, apple-silicon

I don't have an M1 Mac to work with, I read that python supports it. What's the return of these functions on m1 Macs?

```
platform.system()
platform.architecture()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does [platform — Access to underlying platform’s identifying data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html) provide you with your answers

Answer (score 6):

On the actual M1 Mac, the `platform` module returns the following values:

```sh
shuuji3@momo ~ % python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Dec 21 2020, 15:06:03)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'macOS-11.2.3-arm64-arm-64bit'
>>> platform.system()
'Darwin'
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', '')
>>> platform.processor()
'arm'
```

In addition to that, under the Rosetta 2 (Intel mode), the `platform` module returns the different values like followings:

```sh
shuuji3@momo ~ % env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login
shuuji3@momo ~ % python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Dec 21 2020, 15:06:04)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'macOS-11.2.3-x86_64-i386-64bit'
>>> platform.system()
'Darwin'
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', '')
>>> platform.processor()
'i386'
```

Note: For the first command, I'm following the instruction in the article, [How to Run Legacy Command Line Apps on Apple Silicon | Walled Garden Farmers](https://cutecoder.org/software/run-command-line-apple-silicon/).

We could use these values to distinguish under which mode the current M1 mac runs an application.

Answer (score 0):

I got an M1 pro and the outputs are:

```
Python 3.8.15 (default, Nov 10 2022, 13:17:42) 
[Clang 14.0.6 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit'
>>> platform.system()
'Darwin'
```

Answer (score 0):

For additional context, here's a few more values on Intel vs Apple:

```
% arch -x86_64 python3
Python 3.11.4 (v3.11.4:d2340ef257, Jun  6 2023, 19:15:51) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
>>> platform.machine()
'x86_64'
>>> platform.processor()
'i386'

% python3
Python 3.11.4 (v3.11.4:d2340ef257, Jun  6 2023, 19:15:51) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
>>> platform.machine()
'arm64'
>>> platform.processor()
'arm'
```