# What is the difference between `ansible_architecture` and `ansible_machine` on Ansible?

Tags: macos, ansible, ansible-facts, apple-silicon

I'm trying to find the architecture of the machine by using [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts).

We can gather information about the machine by running `ansible -m setup <host-name>` command, as described in the documentation: [Discovering variables: facts and magic variables — Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html).

But it seems that the `ansible_architecture` and `ansible_machine` are the same values. I'm not sure the difference between them. The example on the above documentation shows the following two values which have the same values:

```bash
    "ansible_architecture": "x86_64",
    "ansible_machine": "x86_64",
```

On my M1 MacBook, the result is the same like this:

```bash
shuuji3@momo mac-dev-playbook
> ansible -m setup localhost | egrep '_architecture|_machine'
        "ansible_architecture": "arm64",
        "ansible_machine": "arm64",
```

Can we use these values interchangeably? Or can they have other values in another case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the code (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/platform.py) it's mostly always the same.

The value can differ on Solaris, AIX and OpenBSD.

I guess `ansible_machine` is supposed to be the machine architecture (value of `platform.machine()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html), while `ansible_architecture` is more the OS architecture?

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I can understand why the names are machine and architecture.

Comment: I found the `x86_64` is returned under Rosetta 2 emulation (Intel mode). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66839206/1204782 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/65970469/1204782