# What does Ansible return as `ansible_machine` and `ansible_architecture` under the Rosetta 2 emulation on M1 Mac

Tags: ansible, apple-m1, ansible-facts

On a M1 MacBook, `ansible_architecture` and `ansible_machine` returns the same value that is `arm64`:

```sh
shuuji3@momo mac-dev-playbook
> ansible -m setup localhost | egrep '_architecture|_machine'
        "ansible_architecture": "arm64",
        "ansible_machine": "arm64",
```

What about under the Rosetta 2 emulation on M1 Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the Rosetta 2 emulation (Intel mode) on the M1 Mac, Ansible returns `x86_64` values like the previous intel Mac:

```sh
shuuji3@momo ~ % ansible -m setup localhost | egrep '_architecture|_machine'
        "ansible_architecture": "arm64",
        "ansible_machine": "arm64",

# Run the shell on the Intel mode
shuuji3@momo ~ % env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login

shuuji3@momo ~ % ansible -m setup localhost | egrep '_architecture|_machine'
        "ansible_architecture": "x86_64",
        "ansible_machine": "x86_64",
        "ansible_userspace_architecture": "x86_64",
```

Note that Ansible adds the `ansible_userspace_architecture` fact.

#### References

- [How to Run Legacy Command Line Apps on Apple Silicon | Walled Garden Farmers](https://cutecoder.org/software/run-command-line-apple-silicon/)

Comment: As you will see in the [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/platform.py), ansible basically returns the result of `platform.machine()` of the `platform` python module in both variables except if you are running on AIX or Solaris.