# Is there a list of possible 'ansible_processors' values?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, apple-silicon

I'm running into issues in an Ansible script which has a test for Apple M1 processors.

I have an M2 so I'll need to turn this into a list of processors that we can expand as M3s and what not gets released.

I do however wish to make this list as complete as possible now already and I'm looking for a list of possible values in `ansible_processor`. Or at least what source is used to populate that var.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> *I'm looking for a list of possible values in `ansible_processor`*

you may need to have a look into to source code of the relevant modules, there can be found background information of what is collected for specific environments and setups, in example for your question under [/ansible/module_utils/facts/hardware](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/hardware).

> *Or at least what source is used to populate that var.*

For your OS it should be [`darwin.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/hardware/darwin.py#L79) and as you can see from the source there

```py
    def get_cpu_facts(self):
        cpu_facts = {}
        if 'machdep.cpu.brand_string' in self.sysctl:  # Intel
            cpu_facts['processor'] = self.sysctl['machdep.cpu.brand_string']
...
        else:  # PowerPC
            system_profile = self.get_system_profile()
            cpu_facts['processor'] = '%s @ %s' % (system_profile['Processor Name'], system_profile['Processor Speed'])
...
```

Ansible do not maintain a list of hardware, but get only a string with information back from the OS which it is using then.

Therefore no list of possible values can be provided.

**Further Q&A**

which might also be interesting about gathering facts ...

- [How Ansible gather_facts and sets variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71043335/6771046)
- [What is the exact list of Ansible setup min?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061125/6771046)
- [What does Ansible return as `ansible_machine` and `ansible_architecture` under the Rosetta 2 emulation on M1 Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66839207/6771046)
- [What is the difference between `ansible_architecture` and `ansible_machine` on Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66828315/)

**Documentation**

- [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html)

**Further Readings**

- [What does `platform.system()` and `platform.architecture()` return on Apple M1 Silicon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65970469/)
- [Python `platform.processor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.processor)

Comment: Thank you, not quite what i was hoping for but that answer might not exist.